# Old kitchen light fixture was wired backwards, should I reverse it with the new one?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, wire

After looking through some other posts here about switch loops, I don't think that's the situation I have here. When I pulled off the old light fixture for the kitchen (dual bulb), it had the white wires from the fixture connected to a single black wire, and the black wires of the fixture were connected to three white wires that were wrapped together.

Should I wire up my new led fixture the same way, or was this wrong to begin with and I should reverse it?

In the picture you can see a red cap that has a few black wires from elsewhere in the room, and a single white wire that mates up with the black one that was connected to the fixture.

[image: picture of the old light fixture wired in.]

Comment: I just tested with my volt meter is the black has 115V to ground while the white has nothing, so I'm leaning towards this was wired backwards?

Comment: You are correct then that is was hooked up backwards.  Wire your new fixture black to black and white to white. If your new fixture has a ground wire, hook it up to the bare copper wire in the box.  Type your comment up as an answer since you tested the wires and solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixture was in fact wired up backwards before. After some more searching I found out that by measuring the voltage from each wire to ground I could determine which one was hot. The black wire read 115V to ground so I went with black to black and white to white and it works!